# Understanding why my questions are receiving downvotes

Tags: discussion, support

I've recently discovered SO and am enjoying seeing questions and helping answer other peoples, however when it comes to my own questions, I receive a lot of down votes and I don't understand why.

Question 1 (-2) : ['println needs a message' when trying to use a variable to log, but not when typing it in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62192099/println-needs-a-message-when-trying-to-use-a-variable-to-log-but-not-when-typ)

- Title explains the problem, what I am trying to do is explained, my code is shown as well as full explanations of what I am doing with the code, yet has been down voted.

Question 2 (-1) : ['Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow' error when sending SQLite DB to ArrayList but not String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189681/failed-to-read-row-0-column-1-from-a-cursorwindow-error-when-sending-sqlite)

- Same thing. Title tells the error I am getting. Post fully break downs what I am doing and the code I am using. It even has an alternative version to provide more context, yet has been down voted.

Question 3 (-1): [Converting a table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566613/converting-a-table-to-json)

- Well formatted, has my code, has my solution attempt which isn't fully working and I am asking why.

Like I said, I love SO has a resource, but clearly something is going wrong and if I'm not being told why my posts are being down voted then it makes it difficulty to use and doesn't help me improve them and subsequently add value to the site. I would love it if someone could help me understand this.

Comment: For the first one you did not include the error message so there's a reason for downvotes right there.

Comment: @toolic can I see this on my own posts? As far as I can see, there are no close votes

Comment: @toolic Viewing close votes on your own questions is behind a [250 rep privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: Unfortunately, many users are reluctant to explain their downvotes out of fear that the person they're downvoting will retaliate, either with verbal abuse or by mass-downvoting that user's posts. These fears are real, but the result is that new users instead get upset because they're being downvoted without explanation. It's a lose-lose scenario for everyone involved.

Comment: Most of the reasons for downvotes are explained by either the tooltip shown when hovering over the downvote button ("This question does not show research effort; it is unclear or not useful."), or by a lack of key parts from [ask], or both.

Comment: @F1Krazy they are reluctant, because, some users don't accept their error and start downvoting the question(s) of the commenter, sometimes you get also some more than unfriendly comments

Comment: @nbk Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 17):

The problem I see is that you are not being synthetic and clear enough. You expect the reader to solve the whole issue, not the punctual issue which is blocking you. Your questions seem to have 95% of unnecessary information.

What you are doing is asking something like this:

> I have an error here, why?
>
> ```
> $ ls -l GetterAndSetter.java 
> -rw-r--r-- 1 rodolfoap rodolfoap 410 Jun  4 15:01 GetterAndSetter.java
> $ stats GetterAndSetter.java 
> bash: stats: command not found
> $ stat GetterAndSetter.java 
>   File: GetterAndSetter.java
>   Size: 410           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
> Device: fe03h/65027d    Inode: 4234        Links: 1
> Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/rodolfoap)   Gid: ( 1000/rodolfoap)
> Access: 2020-06-04 15:01:02.369254170 +0200
> Modify: 2020-06-04 15:01:00.493242115 +0200
> Change: 2020-06-04 15:01:00.493242115 +0200
>  Birth: -
> $ cat GetterAndSetter.java 
> public class GetterAndSetter {
>     private int number;
>     public int getNumber() {
>         return this.number;
>     }
>     public int void setNumber(int num) {
>         this.number = num;
>     }
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>     GetterAndSetter a=new GetterAndSetter();
>         a.setNumber(3);
>         System.err.println(a.getNumber());
>     }
> }
> $ less GetterAndSetter.java 
> public class GetterAndSetter {
>     private int number;
>     public int getNumber() {
>         return this.number;
>     }
>     public int void setNumber(int num) {
>         this.number = num;
>     }
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>     GetterAndSetter a=new GetterAndSetter();
>         a.setNumber(3);
>         System.err.println(a.getNumber());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Why the error? What am I doing wrong?

But you can be more precise and go to the point:

> In my java application, I'm having this error:
>
> ```
> GetterAndSetter.java:6: error: <identifier> expected
>     public int void setNumber(int num) {
>               ^
> 1 error
> ```
>
> What is wrong with such line?